# TableViewCell textLabel width issue

Tags: iphone

How can I restrict the width of my aCell.textLabel and aCell.detailTextLabel. I have a big string in textLabel which is overlaying on my detail string. I tried this:
aCell.textLabel.width = aCell.width - 250; but it is not working. Any clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it this way:

```
UILabel *theTitle = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 25)] autorelease];                        
  [theTitle setText:[anObject objectForKey:@"key"];              
  [theTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:[self textLabelFont] size:[[self textLabelFontSize] floatValue]]];                 
  [aCell.contentView addSubview:theTitle];
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best answer, but you might try creating a custom `UITableViewCell` in interface builder. That's what i did last time I had to do anything unusual to a table cell.

DarkDust just posted this tutorial in another question:
http://www.e-string.com/content/custom-uitableviewcells-interface-builder